# Detecting variants of unknown significance

Tags: genetics, biostatistics

I have two groups of people, a healthy population which has carriers of disease and non-carriers, and I have a sick population.  I know the frequency of genetic variants in both groups.  I want to know if I can say anything about the variants with any statistical certainty and how I would do that.

```
Variant      Frequency in Healthy Population    Frequency in Sick Population
X            30                                 25
Y            5                                  700
Z            600                                600
```

Each group (Healthy and Sick) has 1000 people in it.  Can I say anything about each variant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I must admit that I have not a lot of experience with statistical genetics. And I dont fully understand what you mean by "carriers of disease and non-carriers". It is also not totally clear from your question what your goal is. The first thing you could do is a $\chi^{2}$-test to test whether the distributions of variants differ between sick and healthy people:

```
m <- matrix(c(30,5,600,25,700,600), ncol=3, nrow=2, byrow=T)
rownames(m) <- c("Healthy", "Sick")
colnames(m) <- c("X", "Y", "Z")

chisq.test(m)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  m
X-squared = 505.3131, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

So we have strong evidence that the distribution of variants is different between sick and healthy people. If you can assume that the genetic variants are **independent** from each other, you could calculate the [variant-specific odds ratios:](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3154648/pdf/ukmss-34429.pdf)

$$
OR_{X}=\frac{25\cdot 970}{975\cdot 30}=0.83\text{ (95%-CI: 0.46 to 1.47)}
$$
$$
OR_{Y}=\frac{700\cdot 995}{5\cdot 300}=464.33\text{ (95%-CI: 195.31 to 1457.65)}
$$
$$
OR_{Z}=\frac{600\cdot 400}{400\cdot 600}=1.00\text{ (95%-CI: 0.83 to 1.20)}
$$

So people carrying the variant $X$ are a bit less likely to be sick than people who don't carry the variant $X$. Further, carriers of variant $Y$ are 464 times more likely to be sick than non-carriers. Because there are exactly the same number of people carrying variant $Z$ among sick and healthy people, the odds ratio is 1.

You could also run a logistic regression with data on the indicidual level with disease status as outcome (1 = sick, 0 = healthy) and the variants as binary variables (1 = has variant xyz, 0 = doesn't have variant xyz). The exponentiated regression coefficients would then be the variant-specific odds ratios but **adjusted** for the other variants.

Comment: GREAT ANSWER!  My goal was to determine whether there was an statistical evidence to suggest that a particular variant was linked to a disease.  We are trying to determine whether you can say someone is a heterogenous carrier (they have a recessive version of the disease) based on how prevalent it is in both populations.  Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: @user25786 you're welcome! As I said in the post: If you have the data at the individual level (information for each of the 2000 people), you should do a logistic regression because the variants might not be independent. Exponentiate the regression coefficients and the confidence intervals to get the odds ratios + CI for each variant.